# what is the difference between n != null and n.next != null in linkedlist?

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

When writing a while loop to iterate through a linkedlist, what is the difference between using while(n != null) and while(n.next != null)? n being the head of the linkedlist.

Comment: next is the next element. n is the current element.

Answer (score 0):

`while(n!=null)` will traverse the entire list for printing nodes value or counting number of nodes.
`while(n.next!=null)` will stop at the tail (last node) of the linked list.